# Fabricjs Wrong controls area on svg import

Tags: svg, fabricjs

on the kitchensink demo ([link](http://fabricjs.com/kitchensink)), i'm trying to load this svg (grouped):

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
<g id="DEFAULT" display="visible">
<path d="M291.94 240.98L292.64 240.79M292.64 240.79L293.16 240.27M293.16 240.27L293.35 239.57"
fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.5"/>
<path d="M293.35 208.24L293.16 207.54M293.16 207.54L292.64 207.02M292.64 207.02L291.94 206.84"
fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.5"/>
<path d="M293.35 208.24L293.35 239.57"
fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.5"/>
<path d="M231.12 223.91L231.12 223.91"
fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.5"/>
<path d="M231.12 223.91L231.12 239.57"
fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.5"/>
<path d="M231.12 223.91L231.12 208.24"
fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.5"/>
<path d="M232.52 206.84L231.82 207.02M231.82 207.02L231.31 207.54M231.31 207.54L231.12 208.24"
fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.5"/>
<path d="M231.12 239.57L231.31 240.27M231.31 240.27L231.82 240.79M231.82 240.79L232.52 240.98"
fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.5"/>
<path d="M232.52 206.84L291.94 206.84"
fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.5"/>
<path d="M232.52 240.98L291.94 240.98"
fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.5"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

results is :

[image]

as you can see, i have strange selected area... how i can fix the svg in order to obtain correct control area on selecting object?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add these attributes to your SVG so that it's just looking at a portion of the SVG at its current coordinates.

```
<svg ... viewBox="231.12 206.84 62.23 34.14">
```

(I "cheated" to get these values by opening the SVG in Illustrator, changing the artboard to extend only to the edges of the paths, then saving the file again to see what viewBox values it would give me (though of course if you can wrap your head around how the "d" attribute works, which I still can't fully do :), you can presumably just get them with just some arithmetic).)